# Regular expression for URL validation (in JavaScript)

Tags: javascript, regex, validation, url

Does someone have a regex for validating urls (NOT for finding them inside a text passage)? JavaScript snippet would be preferred.

Answer (score 38, accepted):

The actual URL syntax is pretty complicated and not easy to represent in regex. Most of the simple-looking regexes out there will give many false negatives as well as false positives. See for amusement [these efforts](http://flanders.co.nz/2009/11/08/a-good-url-regular-expression-repost/) but even the end result is not good.

Plus these days you would generally want to allow IRI as well as old-school URI, so we can link to valid addresses like:

```
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Þ
http://例え.テスト/
```

I would go only for simple checks: does it start with a known-good method: name? Is it free of spaces and double-quotes? If so then hell, it's probably good enough.

Comment: Ok. At least now I know it's probably not worth the effort in most cases :] Thanks.

Comment: /(ftp|https?):\/\/[^ "]+$/

Comment: Indeed, the right way to validate URLs is not to use a regular expression. Check out the [URI validation code in Node.js](https://github.com/joyent/node/blob/master/lib/url.js). It's far more complex than one regexp, which is why it's always better to use a specialized library rather than roll your own regular expression.

Comment: Two other things to consider: 1) tel:, mailto:, sms: are all valid hosts; 2) mobile browsers (especially iOS) allow other things instead of http/https/ftp for inter-app communication.

Answer (score 92):

In the [accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1411800/638546) [bobince](https://stackoverflow.com/users/18936/bobince) got it right: validating only the scheme name, ://, and spaces and double quotes is usually enough. Here is how the validation can be implemented in JavaScript:

```
var url = 'http://www.google.com';
var valid = /^(ftp|http|https):\/\/[^ "]+$/.test(url);
// true
```

or

```
var r = /^(ftp|http|https):\/\/[^ "]+$/;
r.test('http://www.goo le.com');
// false
```

or

```
var url = 'http:www.google.com';
var r = new RegExp(/^(ftp|http|https):\/\/[^ "]+$/);
r.test(url);
// false
```

References for syntax:

- [MDN RegExp Object](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp)
- [W3Schools RegExp Object](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_obj_regexp.asp)

Comment: @DerekHenderson Here you go, you W3Schools hater ;)

Comment: +1 for getting an unnecessary -1 for W3Schools hate.

Comment: This code won't work for many URLs. When detecting URLs, it's better to rely on a specialized library. [Here's why](http://stackoverflow.com/a/21925491/1269037).

Comment: var r = new RegExp(/^(ftp|http|https):\/\/[^ "]+$/);
the parameter doesn't need '....' when new , just use /^(ftp|http|https):\/\/[^ "]+$/, as my try

Comment: also +1 for getting an unnecessary -1 for W3Schools hate.

Comment: What does `[^ "]` mean in the regex?

Comment: @MiLeung `[^ "]` means any character except a space or a double quote.

Answer (score 28):

Try this regex

```
/(ftp|http|https):\/\/(\w+:{0,1}\w*@)?(\S+)(:[0-9]+)?(\/|\/([\w#!:.?+=&%@!\-\/]))?/
```

It works best for me.

Comment: I think it is best regex for url validation

Comment: This is not working for following urls : www.google.com , gogl.com , http://google.clo , www.google.co.in , www.goo.com.in.ssd

Comment: This code won't work for many URLs. When detecting URLs, it's better to rely on a specialized library. [Here's why](http://stackoverflow.com/a/21925491/1269037).

Comment: Neat, works first try!

Comment: yes works fine with me thank you

Answer (score 7):

I've found some success with this:

```
/^((ftp|http|https):\/\/)?www\.([A-z]+)\.([A-z]{2,})/
```

- It checks one or none of the following: ftp://, http://, or https://
- It requires www.
- It checks for any number of valid characters.
- Finally, it checks that it has a domain and that domain is at least 2 characters.

It's obviously not perfect but it handled my cases pretty well

Comment: "requires www" is like "TLD must be .com". Don't do that.

Answer (score 6):

This REGEX is a patch from @Aamir answer that worked for me

```
/((?:(?:http?|ftp)[s]*:\/\/)?[a-z0-9-%\/\&=?\.]+\.[a-z]{2,4}\/?([^\s<>\#%"\,\{\}\\|\\\^\[\]`]+)?)/gi
```

It matches these URL formats

1. yourwebsite.com
2. yourwebsite.com/4564564/546564/546564?=adsfasd
3. [www.yourwebsite.com](http://www.yourwebsite.com)
4. http://yourwebsite.com
5. https://yourwebsite.com
6. ftp://www.yourwebsite.com
7. ftp://yourwebsite.com
8. http://yourwebsite.com/4564564/546564/546564?=adsfasd

Answer (score 4):

You can simple use `type="url"` in your input and the check it with `checkValidity()` in js

E.g:

your.html

```
<input id="foo" type="url">
```

your.js

```
$("#foo").on("keyup", function() {
    if (this.checkValidity()) {
        // The url is valid
    } else {
        // The url is invalid
    }
});
```

Comment: BTW, I have realize that is worth notice that you should also do some kind of validation in the server side to avoid Injection attacks, as this solution is 100% client-side

Answer (score 3):

```
<html>
<head>
<title>URL</title>
<script type="text/javascript">
    function validate() {
        var url = document.getElementById("url").value;
        var pattern = /(ftp|http|https):\/\/(\w+:{0,1}\w*@)?(\S+)(:[0-9]+)?(\/|\/([\w#!:.?+=&%@!\-\/]))?/;
        if (pattern.test(url)) {
            alert("Url is valid");
            return true;
        } 
            alert("Url is not valid!");
            return false;

    }
</script>

</head>
<body>
URL :
<input type="text" name="url" id="url" />
<input type="submit" value="Check" onclick="validate();" />
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: This code won't work for many URLs. When validating URLs, it's better to rely on a specialized library. [Here's why](http://stackoverflow.com/a/21925491/1269037).

Comment: Using pure JavaScript is better option of validations if you want to customize the pattern you can easily do that in your pattern

Answer (score 3):

After a long research I build this reg expression. I hope it will help others too.......

```
url = 'https://google.co.in';
var re = /[a-z0-9-\.]+\.[a-z]{2,4}\/?([^\s<>\#%"\,\{\}\\|\\\^\[\]`]+)?$/;
if (!re.test(url)) { 
 alert("url error");
return false;
}else{
alert('success')
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this it works for me:

```
 /^(http[s]?:\/\/){0,1}(w{3,3}\.)[-a-z0-9+&@#\/%?=~_|!:,.;]*[-a-z0-9+&@#\/%=~_|]/;
```

Answer (score 2):

I couldn't find one that worked well for my needs. Written and post @ https://gist.github.com/geoffreyrobichaux/0a7774b424703b6c0fffad309ab0ad0a

```js
function validURL(s) {
    var regexp = /^(ftp|http|https|chrome|:\/\/|\.|@){2,}(localhost|\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}|\S*:\w*@)*([a-zA-Z]|(\d{1,3}|\.){7}){1,}(\w|\.{2,}|\.[a-zA-Z]{2,3}|\/|\?|&|:\d|@|=|\/|\(.*\)|#|-|%)*$/gum
    return regexp.test(s);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this [regex](http://snippets.dzone.com/posts/show/452), it works for me:

```
function isUrl(s) {
    var regexp = /(ftp|http|https):\/\/(\w+:{0,1}\w*@)?(\S+)(:[0-9]+)?(\/|\/([\w#!:.?+=&%@!\-\/]))?/
    return regexp.test(s);
}
```

Comment: I'd like to be sure that I will not get false negatives with this regex. You had not problems with it?

Comment: No problems as of yet. Why not conduct tests on the false positives your anticipating?

Comment: It *would* give a false negative for symbols like ';' in the query, *except* that that's a great big `\S+` in the middle of the expression which can expand to match nearly anything, and it's not anchored at the end so you can put any trailing nonsense in. eg. ‘http://@’ or ‘http://I've got a lovely bunch of "coconuts"’ are ‘valid’.

Answer (score 1):

I use the /^[a-z]+:[^:]+$/i regular expression for URL validation. See an example of my cross-browser [InputKeyFilter](https://github.com/anhr/InputKeyFilter) code with URL validation.

```html
<!doctype html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" >
<head>
    <title>Input Key Filter Test</title>
 <meta name="author" content="Andrej Hristoliubov anhr@mail.ru">
 <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"/>
 
 <!-- For compatibility of IE browser with audio element in the beep() function.
 https://www.modern.ie/en-us/performance/how-to-use-x-ua-compatible -->
 <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=9"/>
 
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://rawgit.com/anhr/InputKeyFilter/master/InputKeyFilter.css" type="text/css">  
 <script type="text/javascript" src="https://rawgit.com/anhr/InputKeyFilter/master/Common.js"></script>
 <script type="text/javascript" src="https://rawgit.com/anhr/InputKeyFilter/master/InputKeyFilter.js"></script>
 
</head>
<body>
URL: 
<input type="url" id="Url" value=":"/>
<script>
 CreateUrlFilter("Url", function(event){//onChange event
   inputKeyFilter.RemoveMyTooltip();
   var elementNewInteger = document.getElementById("NewUrl");
   elementNewInteger.innerHTML = this.value;
  }
  
  //onblur event. Use this function if you want set focus to the input element again if input value is NaN. (empty or invalid)
  , function(event){ this.ikf.customFilter(this); }
 );
</script>
 New URL: <span id="NewUrl"></span>

</body>
</html>
```

Also see my page [example of the input key filter](https://anhr.github.io/InputKeyFilter/).

Comment: Doesn't work. It marks this one valid. h://google.com

Comment: h://google.com is valid URL.


"h:"  is valid prefix
See https://www.w3.org/Addressing/URL/url-spec.txt for details.

Examples of valid URL:
mailto:myname@domain.com
https://google.com

If you want filter Hypertext Transfer Protocol only, you need use /^http:\/\/[^:]+$/i regular expression

Answer (score 1):

try with this:

```
 var RegExp =/^(?:(?:https?|ftp):\/\/)(?:\S+(?::\S*)?@)?(?:(?!10(?:\.\d{1,3}){3})(?!127(?:\.\d{1,3}){3})(?!169\.254(?:\.\d{1,3}){2})(?!192\.168(?:\.\d{1,3}){2})(?!172\.(?:1[6-9]|2\d|3[0-1])(?:\.\d{1,3}){2})(?:[1-9]\d?|1\d\d|2[01]\d|22[0-3])(?:\.(?:1?\d{1,2}|2[0-4]\d|25[0-5])){2}(?:\.(?:[1-9]\d?|1\d\d|2[0-4]\d|25[0-4]))|(?:(?:[a-z\u00a1-\uffff0-9]+-?)*[a-z\u00a1-\uffff0-9]+)(?:\.(?:[a-z\u00a1-\uffff0-9]+-?)*[a-z\u00a1-\uffff0-9]+)*(?:\.(?:[a-z\u00a1-\uffff]{2,})))(?::\d{2,5})?(?:\/[^\s]*)?$/i;
```

Answer (score 1):

```
/(?:http[s]?\/\/)?(?:[\w\-]+(?::[\w\-]+)?@)?(?:[\w\-]+\.)+(?:[a-z]{2,4})(?::[0-9]+)?(?:\/[\w\-\.%]+)*(?:\?(?:[\w\-\.%]+=[\w\-\.%!]+&?)+)?(#\w+\-\.%!)?/
```

Comment: I think your expression is missing a `:` between the protocol and `//`. Otherwise, it works fine!

Answer (score 1):

I have tried a few but there were a few issues so I came up with this one.

```
/(https?:\/\/(?:www\d*\.|(?!www\d*\.))[a-zA-Z0-9][a-zA-Z0-9-]+[a-zA-Z0-9]\.[^\s]{2,}|www\d*\.[a-zA-Z0-9][a-zA-Z0-9-]+[a-zA-Z0-9]\.[^\s]{2,}|https?:\/\/(?:www\d*\.|(?!www\d*\.))[a-zA-Z0-9]+\.[^\s]{2,}|www\d*\.[a-zA-Z0-9]+\.[^\s]{2,})/gi;
```

**How to use**

```
const isValidUrl = (url = '') => {
    if (url) {
        var expression =
            /(https?:\/\/(?:www\d*\.|(?!www\d*\.))[a-zA-Z0-9][a-zA-Z0-9-]+[a-zA-Z0-9]\.[^\s]{2,}|www\d*\.[a-zA-Z0-9][a-zA-Z0-9-]+[a-zA-Z0-9]\.[^\s]{2,}|https?:\/\/(?:www\d*\.|(?!www\d*\.))[a-zA-Z0-9]+\.[^\s]{2,}|www\d*\.[a-zA-Z0-9]+\.[^\s]{2,})/gi;
        var regex = new RegExp(expression);
        return !!url.match(regex);
    }
    return false;
};
```

**Breakdown**

```
/(
  https?:\/\/                        # matches http:// or https://
  (?:www\d*\.|(?!www\d*\.)          # matches an optional "www" prefix with zero or more digits, followed by a dot,
                                    # or excludes "www" prefix followed by digits
  )[a-zA-Z0-9][a-zA-Z0-9-]+          # matches the domain name
  [a-zA-Z0-9]\.                      # matches the dot before the top-level domain
  [^\s]{2,}                          # matches the rest of the URL after the domain name
  |                                 # or
  www\d*\.[a-zA-Z0-9][a-zA-Z0-9-]+    # matches the "www" prefix with zero or more digits, followed by a dot, and the domain name
  [a-zA-Z0-9]\.                      # matches the dot before the top-level domain
  [^\s]{2,}                          # matches the rest of the URL after the domain name
  |                                 # or
  https?:\/\/                        # matches http:// or https://
  (?:www\d*\.|(?!www\d*\.)          # matches an optional "www" prefix with zero or more digits, followed by a dot,
                                    # or excludes "www" prefix followed by digits
  )[a-zA-Z0-9]+\.[^\s]{2,}          # matches the domain name and top-level domain
  |                                 # or
  www\d*\.[a-zA-Z0-9]+\.[^\s]{2,}    # matches the "www" prefix with zero or more digits, followed by a dot, and the domain name and top-level domain
)/gi;
```

**Valid URLs**

```
http://www.example.com
https://www.example.co.uk
http://www1.example.com
http://www2.example.com
http://www3.example.com
https://www1.example.co.uk
https://www2.example.co.uk
https://www3.example.co.uk
https://example.com
http://example.com
www.example.com
www1.example.com
www2.example.com
www3.example.com
www.example.co.uk
www1.example.co.uk
www2.example.co.uk
www3.example.co.uk
```

**Invalid URLs**

```
example
example.com
ftp://example.com
ftp://www.example.com
http://www.example
http://www.example.
http://www.example/
http://example./com
```

Answer (score 0):

```
/^(http|ftp)s?:\/\/((?=.{3,253}$)(localhost|(([^ ]){1,63}\.[^ ]+)))$/
```

**explanation:**

1. URL can start with `http` / `ftp`
2. `s` can follow, but not necessarily
3. `://` are a must right after
4. Maximum length of domain labels with TLD is 253. What we see here is a lookup to check that total length is min 3 (i.e `http://a.b`) and max of 253
5. Then there's either `localhost` or `domain-name.TLD`.
   domain-name can be made out of multiple labels, divided by a `dot` (i.e `https://inner.sub.domain.net`),
   and maximum length of each label is 63.
   I didn't see anywhere that there's limitation on the TLD length, so I didn't put there any restriction.

---

What @bobince answered is a real concern.

The latest answers are very close (thanks @Akseli), **but they all miss the obligatory** `dot` in the URL and lengths.
The answer I provide above deals with those too.

for further reading:

- [is there a url without a dot?](https://www.quora.com/Is-there-a-URL-without-a-dot-a-full-stop-in-it?share=1)
- [Names and maximum lengths of the parts of a URL](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66660651/5762431)

Answer (score 0):

From https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/how-to-validate-urls-in-javascript/

```
function isValidHttpUrl(str) {
  const pattern = new RegExp(
    '^(https?:\\/\\/)?' + // protocol
      '((([a-z\\d]([a-z\\d-]*[a-z\\d])*)\\.)+[a-z]{2,}|' + // domain name
      '((\\d{1,3}\\.){3}\\d{1,3}))' + // OR ip (v4) address
      '(\\:\\d+)?(\\/[-a-z\\d%_.~+]*)*' + // port and path
      '(\\?[;&a-z\\d%_.~+=-]*)?' + // query string
      '(\\#[-a-z\\d_]*)?$', // fragment locator
    'i'
  );
  return pattern.test(str);
}

console.log(isValidHttpUrl('https://www.freecodecamp.org/')); // true
console.log(isValidHttpUrl('mailto://freecodecamp.org')); // false
console.log(isValidHttpUrl('freeCodeCamp')); // false
```

Answer (score 0):

Using the power of javascript only, a good approach in some cases is to use

```
let urlToValidate = `${decodeURIComponent(url)}`

const isValidUrl = (url = '') => {
    try {
        new URL(url);
        return true;
    } catch (error) {
        return false;
    }
};

let result = isValidUrl(urlToValidate)
console.log(result)
```