# Names and maximum lengths of the parts of a URL

Tags: url, subdomain

In this URL:

```
http://www.subdomain.domainname.abc.xyz.com.us/directory/filename.extension
```

1. What is the name of each part?
2. What is maximum length of each part? e.g. subdomain, domain name, top-level domain…

Comment: @HoldOffHunger 's answer covers the thing that brought me here, wondering about top-level domain limit. It seems the actual limit is, to paraphrase, "pretty long". However, in real-life practice of various email format regexes, I have generally seen 6 as the limit, citing "museum" as the classic example. I would be curious to know how people are dealing with this in real life.

Answer (score 35):

The Wikipedia entry for [Subdomain](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subdomain#Overview) answers both questions:

1. *What is the name of each part?*

> A **subdomain** is a domain that is part of a larger domain; the only domain that is not also a subdomain is the [root domain](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Root_domain). For example, `west.example.com` and `east.example.com` are subdomains of the `example.com` domain, which in turn is a subdomain of the com [top-level domain](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Top-level_domain) (TLD). A "subdomain" expresses relative dependence, not absolute dependence: for example, `wikipedia.org` comprises a subdomain of the `org` domain, and `en.wikipedia.org` comprises a subdomain of the domain `wikipedia.org`.

2. *What is maximum length of each part? e.g. subdomain, domain name,
   top-level domain…*

> In theory this subdivision can go down to 127 levels deep, and each [DNS label](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DNS_label) can contain up to 63 characters, as long as the whole domain name does not exceed a total length of 255 characters. But in practice most domain registries limit at 253 characters.

Answer (score 12):

### TLDR - The Names

Given `foo://example.com:8042/over/there?name=ferret#nose`, your components can break down as follows, according to [**RFC3986**](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3986) (January 2005)...

```
     foo://subdomain.example.com:8042/over/there?name=ferret#nose
     \_/  \________/                /\_________/ \_________/ \__/
      |       |                          |            |        |
          \___|_____________________/
   scheme   label       authority       path        query   fragment
   (AKA:                (AKA:
   protocol)            (domain)
```

### TLDR - The Maximum Lengths

- Label / Subdomain: `63` characters maximum.
- Domain: `253` characters maximum
- Total URL: `2,000` characters maximum

### The Details

Now, let's break this down for an alternate version of your given URL `http://www.subdomain.domainname.com/directory/filename.extension?name=ferret#nose`:

#### Protocol

- `http://` : The scheme, or protocol.

  - Max Length: No limits are imposed, but these are typically created by the IETF, so the longest, RFC'd scheme would be the max, which I see as `prospero`, `8` characters.  *However!*  You can make your own protocol and have it be any reasonable length, though I would probably not exceed `255` characters.  For instance, `file:/` in Chrome will show the file, `samba:/` in Linux will launch the Samba application and access the resource, etc., etc..
  - Source: [**RFC1738**](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc1738) (December 1994)
  - Quote: *"Notes on particular protocols follow. The schemes covered are: ftp, http, gopher, mailto, news, nntp, telnet, wais, file, prospero."*

#### SubDomain

- `www`, `subdomain` : `www` is just a popular sub-domain that is superfluous today.

  - Max Length: `63` characters
  - Source: [**RFC1035**](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc1035) (November 1987)
  - Quote: *"Labels must be 63 characters or less."*

#### Domain

- `domainname.com` : Your "domain," not any level of it but the full domain.

  - Max Length: `253` characters if you care about E-mail (max limit of the `to` field in SMTP is `255` characters, leaving you with `a@(253-char-domain)` as the longest possible domain in an email; `255` if you don't mind E-mail not working
  - Source: [**RFC2821**](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2821) (October 2008), [**RFC5321**](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5321) (October 2008), [**RFC821**](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc821) (August 1982)
  - Quote:

> *The maximum total length of a domain name or number is 255 characters.* (RFC2821, RFC5321)
>
> *[The email address format is] `<mailbox> ::= <local-part> "@" <domain>`* (RFC821)

#### Second-Level Domain

- `domainname` : Your second-level domain.

  - Same limits and source as subdomains.

#### Top-Level Domain

- `com` : Your top-level domain (TLD).  This may also contain a period in it, like `co.uk`.

  - Max Length: These are established by RFC's by the IETF.  The max length will be whatever the longest TLD exists.  For instance, [**RFC6927**](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6927) reserved the domain `.XN--MGBERP4A5D4AR` for Saudi Arabia.
  - Source: [**RFC920**](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc920) (October 1984)
  - Quote: *"The initial top level domain names are: ARPA, GOV, EDU, COM, MIL, ORG."*

#### Path

- `directory/filename.extension` : This is your path.

  - Max Length: `Infinite`, ***but in practice, please stick to URLs no longer than `2,000` characters***, as not all browsers can understand the concept of infinite.
  - Source: [**RFC3986**](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3986) (January 2005), [**RFC2616**](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2616) (June 1999), [**RFC7230**](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7230#section-3.1.1)
  - Quote:

> *"Servers MUST be able to handle the URI of any resource they serve, and SHOULD be able to handle URIs of unbounded length..."* (RFC2616);
>
> *"This specification does not limit the scope of what might be a resource..."* (RFC3986);
>
> *"It is RECOMMENDED that all HTTP senders and recipients support, at a minimum, request-line lengths of 8000 octets." (RFC7230)

#### Query and Fragment

- `name=ferret` : This is a `GET` parameter, in the form of `field=value`.
- `#nose` : This is the fragment, which can be used to anchor to a specific section of an HTML document using the `<a name="nose" />` HTML.

  - Max: As described in the section above on the path, the total path, query, and fragment should not exceed `2,000` characters.
  - Source: [**RFC3986**](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3986) (January 2005)
  - Quote:

> `URI         = scheme ":" hier-part [ "?" query ] [ "#" fragment ]`

Answer (score 11):

To answer question 1:

A simple URI would look something like:

```
http://www.mywebsite.com
```

It's easier to explain right to left:

- com is the top level domain (TLD)
- mywebsite is the domain, but would typically include the TLD when describing, e.g. mywebsite.com
- www is a subdomain
- http:// is the protocol used to access the resource

Just to make things a little more confusing, many top level domains are actually 2 domains, such as .co.uk

So, another example would be:

```
https://aaa.bbb.ccc.mywebsite.co.uk
```

- co.uk is the TLD
- mywebsite is the domain
- ccc is a subdomain
- bbb is a sub-subdomain, or you could say a subdomain of ccc.mywebsite.co.uk
- aaa is a sub-sub-subdomain, or you could say a subdomain of bbb.ccc.mywebsite.co.uk

Anything after the TLD but before the filename is called the path, e.g:

```
https://www.mywebsite.com/this/is/a/path/to/resource/filename.txt
```

In the above example filename.txt is usually called a resource (although some would say the whole line is the resource, because you don't always have a filename).