# Regex get domain name from email

Tags: regex

I am learning regex and am having trouble getting `google` from email address

String

```
first.name@google.com
```

I just want to get google, not google.com

Regex:

```
[^@].+(?=\.)
```

Result: https://regex101.com/r/wA5eX5/1

From my understanding. It ignore `@` find a string after that until `.` (dot) using `(?=\.)`

What did I do wrong?

Comment: The `[^@]` is one non `@`. The `.+` one or more of any character (excluding new line). Try https://regex101.com/r/wA5eX5/2

Answer (score 33, accepted):

`[^@]` means "match one symbol that is *not* an `@` sign. That is not what you are looking for - use lookbehind `(?<=@)` for `@` and your `(?=\.)` lookahead for `\.` to extract server name in the middle:

```
(?<=@)[^.]+(?=\.)
```

The middle portion `[^.]+` means "one or more non-dot characters".

[Demo.](https://regex101.com/r/vE8rP9/1)

Comment: Thank you. It appear work fine if you take out `(?=\.)`

Comment: @I'll-Be-Back That is true - `[^.]` takes care of that. However, if an address looks like this `a@google`, expression without `(?=\.)` look-ahead would still match `google`, while expression with the look-ahead would reject such string as invalid.

Comment: `(?<=@)[^.]+(?=\.).*` for everything after `@`, including subdomain

Comment: Lookbehinds are only supported by Chrome

Comment: @yairniz That's not true, lookbehinds are supported by many regex engines, such as ones supplied with .NET and Java.

Comment: @dasblinkenlight Please add a warning not to use on web it breaks on Firefox right now

Comment: @yairniz that would be unwarranted because the question is not tagged for the web; it’s a “generic” regex question.

Comment: @dasblinkenlight You are correct but better safe than sorry

Comment: Be careful! This solution does not consider subdomains, and treats a subdomain as if it were the domain. If you need to extract domains from email addresses that have a subdomain, try another solution.

Answer (score 20):

**Updated answer:**
Use a [capturing group](http://www.regular-expressions.info/brackets.html) and *keep it simple :)*

```
@(\w+)
```

*Explanation by splitting it up*
`(` *capturing group* for extraction `)`
`\w` stands for [word character](http://www.regular-expressions.info/shorthand.html) `[A-Za-z0-9_]`
`+` is a [quantifier](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3206d374(v=vs.110).aspx) for *one or more* occurances of `\w`

[Regex explanation and demo on Regex101](https://regex101.com/r/vJ4dJ9/5)

Answer (score 8):

I used the solution's regex for my task, but realized that some of the emails weren't that easy: `foo@us.industries.com`, `foobar@tm.valves.net`, and`foo@ge.test.com`

To anyone who came here wanting the sub domain as well (or is being cut off by it), here's the regex:

```
(?<=@)[^.]*.[^.]*(?=\.)
```

Comment: This is the correct solution to cater for domains with subdomains.

Comment: Thanks for sharing, but seem it's not working well such structure name.surname@subd.maind.com

Comment: Also this won't work with domains with the following structure: `domain.co.uk`

Comment: @DanielChepenko I'm not sure what you are trying to grab, but the sub and main are being grabbed the way I've mentioned above. https://regex101.com/r/DUrvDI/1

Answer (score 5):

As I was working to get the domain name of email addresses and none corresponded to what I needed:

- To not catch subdomains
- To match countries top domains (like `.com.ar` or `co.jp`)

For example, in `test@ext.domain.com.mx` I need to match `domain.com.mx`

So I made this one:

`[^.@]*?\.\w{2,}$|[^.@]*?\.com?\.\w{2}$`

Here is a link to regex101 to illustrate the regex: https://regex101.com/r/vE8rP9/59

You can get the sumdomain name (without the top-level domain ex: `.com` or `.com.mx`) by adding lookaround operators (but it will match twice in `test@test.com.mx`):

`[^.@]*?(?=\.\w{2,}$)|[^.@]*?(?=\.com?\.\w{2}$)`

Answer (score 3):

This should be the regex:

```
(?<=@)[^.]+
```

`(?<=@)` - places the search right after the `@`
`[^.]+` - take all the characters that are not dot (stops on dot)

So it extracts `google` from the email address.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe not strictly a "full regex answer" but more flexible ( in case the part before the @ is not "first.last") would be using cut:

```
cut -d @ -f 2 | cut -d . -f 1
```

The first cut will isolate the part after @ and the second one will get what you want.
This will work also for another kinds of email patterns : xxxx@server.com / xxx.yyy.zzz@ server.com and so on...

Answer (score 2):

Thanks everyone for your great responses, I took what you had and expanded it with labelled match-groups for easy extraction of separate parts.

##### Caveat : Regex.Speed = Slow

Another post mentioned how **SLOW** and nonperformant regexes are, and that is a fair point to remember. My particular need is targeting my own background/slow/reporting processes and therefore it doesn't matter how long it takes.
But it's good to remember whenever possible Regex should NOT be used in any sort of web page load or *"needs-to-be-quick"* kind of application.  In that case you're much better off using substring to algorithmically strip down the inputs and throw away all the junk that I'm optionally matching/allowing/including here.

https://regex101.com/r/ZnU3OC/1

### One Regex to rule them all...

- Subdomain/Domain/TopLevelDomain/CountryCode extraction for Emails, domain lists, & URLs
- Also handles ?Querystring=junk, Slashes/With/Paths, #anchors
- Now with more broth, batteries not included

```
^(?<Email>.*@)?(?<Protocol>\w+:\/\/)?(?<SubDomain>(?:[\w-]{2,63}\.){0,127}?)?(?<DomainWithTLD>(?<Domain>[\w-]{2,63})\.(?<TopLevelDomain>[\w-]{2,63}?)(?:\.(?<CountryCode>[a-z]{2}))?)(?:[:](?<Port>\d+))?(?<Path>(?:[\/]\w*)+)?(?<QString>(?<QSParams>(?:[?&=][\w-]*)+)?(?:[#](?<Anchor>\w*))*)?$
```

*not overly complicated at all... why would you even say that?*
[image: Jex-Regex-Visualization]

##### Substitution / Outputs

```
EXAMPLE INPUT: "https://www.stackoverflow.co.uk/path/2?q=mysearch&and=more#stuff"
EXAMPLE OUTPUT:
{
  Protocol:            "https://"
  SubDomain:           "www"
  DomainWithTLD:       "stackoverflow.co.uk"
  Domain:              "stackoverflow"
  TopLevelDomain:      "co"
  CountryCode:         "uk"
  Path:                "/path/2"
  QString:             "?q=mysearch&and=more#stuff"
}
```

##### Allowed/Compliant Domains : Should ALL MATCH

```
www.bankofamerica.com
bankofamerica.com.securersite.regexr.com
bankofamerica.co.uk.blahblahblah.secure.com.it
dashes-bad-for-seo.but-technically-still-allowed.not-in-front-or-end
bit.ly
is.gd
foo.biz.pl
google.com.cn
stackoverflow.co.uk
level_three.sub_domain.example.com
www.thelongestdomainnameintheworldandthensomeandthensomemoreandmore.com
https://www.stackoverflow.co.uk?q=mysearch&and=more
foo://5th.4th.3rd.example.com:8042/over/there
foo://subdomain.example.com:8042/over/there?name=ferret#nose
example.com
www.example.com
example.co.uk
trailing-slash.com/
trailing-pound.com#
trailing-question.com?
probably-not-valid.com.cn?&#
probably-not-valid.com.cn/?&#
example.com/page
example.com?key=value

* NOTE: PunyCodes (Unicode in urls) handled just fine with \w ,no extra sauce needed
xn--fsqu00a.xn--0zwm56d.com
xn--diseolatinoamericano-66b.com
```

##### Emails : Should ALL MATCH

```
first.name@google1.co.com
foo@us.industries.com,
foobar@tm.valves.net,
andfoo@ge.test.com
jane.doe@my-bank.no
john.doe@spam.com
jane.ann.doe@sandnes.district.gov
```

##### Non-Compliant Domains : Should NOT MATCH

- either not long-enough (domain min length 2), or too long (64)

```
v.gd
thing.y
0123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567891234.com
its-sixty-four-instead-of-sixty-three!.com
symbols-not-allowed@.com
symbols-not-allowed#.com
symbols-not-allowed$.com
symbols-not-allowed%.com
symbols-not-allowed^.com
symbols-not-allowed&.com
symbols-not-allowed*.com
symbols-not-allowed(.com
symbols-not-allowed).com
symbols-not-allowed+.com
symbols-not-allowed=.com
```

##### TBD Not handled:

```
* dashes as start or ending is disallowed (dropped from Regex for readability)
-junk-.com 
* is underscore allowed? i donno... (but it simplifies the regex using \w instead of [a-zA-Z0-9\-] everywhere)
symbols-not-allowed_.com

* special case localhost?
.localhost
```

also see:

##### Domain Name Rules :: Super handy ASCII Diagram of a URL

- see: https://stackoverflow.com/a/66660651/738895 *

---

- Side NOTE: lazy load '?' for subdomains{0,127}? currently needed for any of the cases with country codes... (example: stackoverflow.co.uk)
- Matches these, but does NOT grab $NLevelSubdomains in a match group, can only grab 3rd level only.

Answer (score 0):

This is a relatively simple regex, and it grabs everything between the `@` and the final domain extension (e.g. .com, .org). It allows domain names that are made up of non-word characters, which exist in real-world data.

```
>>> regex = re.compile(r"^.+@(.+)\.[\w]+$")

>>> regex.findall('jane.doe@my-bank.no')
['my-bank']

>>> regex.findall('john.doe@spam.com')
['spam']

>>> regex.findall('jane.ann.doe@sandnes.district.gov')
['sandnes.district']
```

Comment: Unfortunately it doesn't work for emails like `yahoo.co.uk`. I just want `yahoo` in this case.

Answer (score 0):

I used this regular expression to get the complete domain name `'.*@+(.*)'` where `.*` will ignore all the character before `@ (by @+)` and start extracting cpmlete domain name by mentioning paranthesis and complete string inside(except linebrake characters)

Comment: Why `@+`? `@` must be present **once** in email.Try your regex with `mymail@example.com blah blah`

Answer (score 0):

`[^\@][a-zA-Z0-9$&+,;=?#|'<>.^*()%!-]+$` for the ones looking for something compatible with golang to extract domain name from email address with regex.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a ***reliable source*** for email addresses, such as an email application API, the following regular expression will allow the domain to be extracted:

```
(?<Domain>[\w-]{2,63})\.(?:[\w-]{2,63}?)(?:\.(?:[a-z]{2}))?$
```

Here, you can use the named capture, 'Domain'. This takes subdomains into account by ignoring them, and only focuses on the end of every line. Note that the regular expression doesn't actually focus on a subdomain at all, if one exists, but it does need to match a top level domain (and potentially a country code) separately.

***Don't use this regular expression if you are processing an email address directly from user input.*** This solution was inspired by m1m1k's answer, and m1m1k's answer should be used instead if the email address needs to be sanitised.