# Extract domain from email address with Regex

Tags: regex

I'm learning regular expressions and I'm having trouble extracting the domain from the email address. I have an email address: example@gmail.com. I need to use a regular expression to extract @gmail (along with the @ symbol). I should end up only getting example. I've already tried this:

`your text`@(\w+)
and this
`your text`(?<=@)[^.]+(?=.).*
but those expressions didn't work properly. I'd appreciate your help.

Comment: you can found the response here https://stackoverflow.com/a/39027263/8081292

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Regex get domain name from email](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39027204/regex-get-domain-name-from-email)

Answer (score 0):

I just tried a simple look behind - @(?<=@).* it will match @google.com you can also group the entire expression and can change it according to single and multi-line matches.

```
@(?<=@).*
```

[image]

Comment: Please do not answer questions which are obvious duplicates with accepted answers.

Comment: @ljmc - thank you for the information, I did not realize that tbh. also if it is a duplicate question then this should be closed no?

Comment: I have flagged it as duplicate as you can see from my comment. Feel free to flag as well, and hopefully it gets reviewed soon and closed.