# What is the part "baltimore.legistar" of the URL "http://baltimore.legistar.com" called?

Tags: url, dns, terminology

What is it called when a website's domain is like:

```
http://baltimore.legistar.com
```

What is the `baltimore.legistar` part called?

I see this sometimes where there's a large website and they appended something else to it such as:

```
www.bigwebsite._____.org
```

Comment: Check this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10552665/names-and-maximum-lengths-of-the-parts-of-a-url they explain what a subdomain is an what are the parts of a URL.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think for your webpage legistar is the main `domain` and baltimore is a `subdomain`.

> 1. Protocol - The beginning of the url with https/http
> 2. Domain name - The unique part to your URL. e.g. `google` in https://www.google.com/
> 3. Path name - The path to a page on your website.

See https://doepud.co.uk/blog/anatomy-of-a-url for reference.