# javascript url regexp restrict multiple http(s)/www

Tags: javascript, regex, url

here is my regexp

```
var url_reg = /^(http[s]?:\/\/|ftp:\/\/)?(www\.)?[a-zA-Z0-9-\.]+\.(com|org|net|mil|edu|ca|in|au)+/;
```

it works fine for single input like https://www.google.com , but
it allows double or more "http/https/www" like below -

https://www.google.com/https://www.google.com/

url can also include folder like google.com/folder/file

i need to validate single occurrence of valid url.

Can anyone help me?

Comment: put `\/?$` before the last `/`

Comment: Also `https://www.google.com/https://www.google.com/` is actually a valid url IIRC

Comment: @Liam this is JavaScript :p not C#

Comment: @EaterOfCode the regex will work in both languages, though.

Comment: Obviously not quite awake yet, try this then [Regular expression for URL validation (in JavaScript)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1410311/regular-expression-for-url-validation-in-javascript)

Comment: @EaterOfCode url can also include folder name like https://www.google.com/folder/file

Comment: if you want that you can better use what @Liam gave you

Answer (score 0):

To validate a URL, you can use a regex. This is what I use. A valid URL per the URL spec. The URL you have provided, is actually a valid URL per the [URL spec](http://www.w3.org/Addressing/URL/url-spec.txt).

```
/^((((https?|ftps?|gopher|telnet|nntp):\/\/)|(mailto:|news:))(%[0-9A-Fa-f]{2}|[-()_.!~*';\/?:@&=+$,A-Za-z0-9])+)([).!';/?:,][[:blank:]])?$/
```

This was borrowed from [OSWAP](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/OWASP_Validation_Regex_Repository)