# (Discord.js) Bot to delete all URLs posted

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm, discord, discord.js

I want my bot to delete the URLs posted by the members.
Im not sure about how to detect that a URL has been posted as they could start from https or www. Or something else altogether...
And insight is appreciated !

EDIT: 
Found similar question to mine.

[Regular expression for URL validation (in JavaScript)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1410311/regular-expression-for-url-validation-in-javascript)

Successfully tackled the same using a npm plugin called [Linkify](http://soapbox.github.io/linkifyjs/).

Consider this closed.

Comment: What have you tried so far? Do you know how to make a basic bot?

Comment: I've a well made bot with complex features like Giveaway , MySQL based XP levels etc.. I just want to know what should I compare the message to identify it as a url

Comment: Ok good to know - I'd recommend adding more detail to your question (like what you've tried - a.k.a. a super simple basic bot with a section that shows where your URL-checking code *COULD* go). Since right now your question has 3 votes to be closed... FYI

Comment: Have you looked at regex expressions? Here's an interesting SO question about URL Validation (in javascript) via regex: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1410311/regular-expression-for-url-validation-in-javascript

Comment: Thats great help, I will see where to go from there, all I wanted was a starting point ... How do I close /mark this a answered

Comment: Cool, hope it gets you where you need to go. I added that comment in an answer below, so you can mark it accepted and that pretty much closes it up.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd recommend looking into regular expressions (regex) for URL Validation.

Here's another SO question that you can use as a starting point: [Regular expression for URL validation (in JavaScript)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1410311/regular-expression-for-url-validation-in-javascript)

One recommended approach is using a regex string like this (from an answer in that question):

```
/^(ftp|http|https):\/\/[^ "]+$/.test(url)
```

This expression matches a full string, so you'll have to either edit this regex to match **any** place inside a string, or do some message content manipulation before using that regex.