# Accept only specified type of url in vuelidate library Vue js 2

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vee-validate, vuelidate, vue-validator

I am using vuelidate library to validate the URL. I wanted input only to accept specific URL types. They are "http://www.example.com", "https://www.example.com", "www.example.com" .
If entered URL not matched with the above-mentioned patterns, then I need an error.
Below is my code

```
import { maxLength, url } from "vuelidate/lib/validators";
export default {
  data() {
    return {
      form: {
        homepageUrl: null,
      },
    };
  },
  validations: {
    form: {
      homepageUrl: { url, maxLength: maxLength(150) },
    },
  },
}
```

Note: **It could be any domain like .net .co.in .com .it .av .let**

Comment: What do you mean by "other than these"? What about `https://example.com`? `https://example.io`? `https://example.co.uk`? `https://www.example.com:8080/`? Are URLs with hashes/query strings allowed?

Comment: @Terry, now I updated the question, please check. I wanted input only accepts patterns is  "http://www.example.com", "https://www.example.com", "www.example.com".

Comment: So all other top level domains will be rejected? Like `https://example.org`?

Comment: See: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1410311/regular-expression-for-url-validation-in-javascript

Comment: no, it could be any domain like .org, .net .co.in .com .it .av .le

Comment: Then do update your question because it is misleading and doesn't accurately show what you intend the validation to do. The best approach with these questions is to give multiple examples of what is considered valid _and_ invalid.